# Correlation between independent explanatory variables in regression

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, correlation, beta

```
sample_size = 100
x1 = rnorm(sample_size, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)
x2 = rnorm(sample_size, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)
x3 = 0.5*x2+rnorm(sample_size, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)
```

## generate errors:

```
epsilon = rnorm(sample_size, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
```

## generate dependent variable:

```
y = 0+0.1*x1+0.2*x2+0.3*x3+epsilon
```

Case 1 :x1 and x2 are independent variables.
correlation should come to 0 as we increase sample size ie. cor(x1,x2)

Case 2: But seeing the equation in terms of x2,

```
x2=(5*y-0.5*x1-1.5*x3)
```

it says the beta should be -0.5
' correlation =beta*var(x)/var(y)'
correlation= -0.5*var(x1)/var(x2)
which states that correlation should not be zero.

Where am i going wrong in this second case???

Comment: This would be a better fit on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: question is very confusing. in your second case you evaluate `x2` to -0.5, but that is not a coefficient. you set the coefficient/beta to 0.2 when you generated your DV

Comment: x2=f(y)  has beta of -0.5 (x2= (beta1*y-beta2*x1-beta3*x3) and beta2 = -0.5)                       and y=f(x) has different beta , i am talking about the case where beta is -0.5 ie. x2=f(y)